# Aliases for using common SRFIs in Chicken Scheme

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

Chicken comes with most of the major SRFIs that I'd want, but one thing that I find very frustrating is that, as far as I can tell, I have to use them by number. Even if I might remember that `(use srfi-69)` really means "use hash tables", other people on my project don't--and even I don't necessarily remember more rarely used monickers, like `srfi-14`. (Multithreading, if you're curious.)

Is there some alias system for the SRFIs so that I could write something closer to `(use hashtables)` instead? Alternatively, is there a way I can just tell Chicken to engage all the built-in SRFIs when I start it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got the power!

You can make a module called "hash tables" and import srfi-69 and export all of it.

Of course this would simplify things for you, but for people that know their SRFIs it's not obvious that it's the same as srfi-69 until they read the source. I think it's best just memorizing the numbers..

Comment: What Sylwester said.  And as for making all SRFIs available, you can check out the [big-chicken](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/big-chicken) egg, which is one big module that exposes everything that's built in.